# AWS EC2 and Redshift Security group connection error

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect AWS Redshift instance through SQL Workbench installed on the same EC2 Instance but its repeatedly giving an error of
"connection refused check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP"
I am using SQL Workbench on a EC2 Instance with security group defined inside EC2 Instance but I cannot define security group in the cluster due to non-classic mode.

Can anyone let me know what is the correct solution the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to redshift AWS console
GO to Security. Select your redshift security group.
in connection type add EC2 Security Group. Here please select the security group of EC2 
where you have SQL workbench installed.

Other option in use CIDR/IP connection type and put public ip of EC2 box e.g. 123.123.123.123/32

Comment: i am trying to access my RedShift from SQL workbench in my local computer... the EC2 security group used in my redshift allows `All TCP`, `All UDP`, `ALL ICMP` from source `0.0.0.0/0` over port numbers `0-65535`... it still says **Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections**... What am i missing out?