# cannot access AWS redshift (EC2-classic) from SQL workbench in local computer despite all open Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, icmp

This question is ***NOT the same*** as: [**AWS EC2 and Redshift Security group connection error**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845396/aws-ec2-and-redshift-security-group-connection-error)

i am trying to access my RedShift (using ***EC2-classic*** and not using ***VPC***) from SQL workbench in my local computer. The EC2 security group used in my redshift allows:

`All TCP`,

`All UDP`,

`ALL ICMP`

from sources `0.0.0.0/0`

over port numbers `0-65535`

It still says "**Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections**".

What am i missing out?

---

---

---

### Redshift cluster security group screen

[image: Redshift cluster security group screen]

---

---

---

### EC2 security group screen

[image: EC2 security group screen]

---

---

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, thanks to some prompt tweets from RahulPathak where he said:

Tweet 1 - [link to tweet](https://twitter.com/rahulpathak/status/513782415530008576):

> security group enables access from EC2 instances. You need CIDR rules for your local machine

Tweet 2 - [link to tweet](https://twitter.com/rahulpathak/status/513786781896962048):

> security group only counts for ec2 instances. you’ll need CIDR rules on the cluster for local machine.

So go to your Redshift cluster security group page, and authorize a new `CIDR/IP` connection type for your cluster security group. Then add the CIDR/IP value as needed for your secure setup.

---

After searching a bit further, the **relevant AWS documentation** was found [*** *in this page* ***](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-refusal-failure-issues.html) where it says:

> If you attempt to connect to the cluster from a client tool outside of
>   the network that the cluster is in, you must add an ingress rule to
>   the cluster security group for the CIDR/IP that you are connecting
>   from...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run in VPC configuration, not EC2 Classic.
One possiblity is that the VPC/subnet your Redshift cluster is running in is not accessible from the Internet.

Start up an instance in the same subnet. In the Redshift security group
allow all traffic from subnet (or VPC CIDR) to the port Redshift is
running on. Looks like you got that already as you allow from anywhere.
Try to telnet from that instance to the Redshift cluster
(telnet  ). You have to get a connection or your
port or security group setting is off. Within the subnet the Redshift
endpoint resolves to the internal IP address, so it's down to the SG to
allow connection.

When this works, but you cannot connect from the outside there are a
couple of options. You are missing the IGW on the VPC, or the route on the
subnet to the IGW to route the Internet/public traffic to the cluster or
the SG blocks the traffic. The missing IGW/route you will most likely
experience when you are not able to directly connect to the instance you
spun up in the same subnet as Redshift.

Comment: i am not using VPC... i am running it from EC2-classic.... updated my question accordingly... sorry for not mentioning it earlier